# Prove norm of matrix greater than spectral radius

Tags: matrices, spectral-radius, matrix-norms

> Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with spectral radius $\sigma(A) = 1$, prove that there is an $m_0$ so that $\|A^m\| > 1$ for every $m \geq m_0$.

#### Solution attempt:

I think the question is in error, and I think the question should state $||A^m||\geq1$ instead of $||A^m||>1$. I found a proposition which states for any $k\geq 1$, $\sigma (A) \leq||A^k||^{\frac{1}{k}}$

By the proposition, $$||A^k||^{\frac{1}{k}}\geq\sigma(A)=1\\
(||A^k||^{\frac{1}{k}})^k \geq 1^k=1\\
\text{thus,}\,||A^k||\geq 1$$

Does anyone think this solution is incorrect? If so, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Which matrix norm are you using?

Answer (score 2):

For example, $\|I^m\| = 1 = \sigma(I)$ for all $m$, so $\|A^m\|>1$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there  is  an error in the question. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remark: one can show that

$$\sigma(A)= \inf \{||A^k||^{\frac{1}{k}}: k \in \mathbb N\}= \lim_{k \to \infty}||A^k||^{\frac{1}{k}}.$$

Comment: I never saw the infimum part of this expression, and I thought $\sigma(A)\leq $lim$_{k\rightarrow \infty}||A^k||^\frac{1}{k}$ ? (You have $=$ not $\leq$)

How does one come up with the inf expression?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius,  Gelfand's formula.